# Solr terms facet ratio

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a simple requirement. I need to retrieve from solr the ratio of values in a terms facet. Let's suppose my documents are all like:

```
{
  myTerm : "OK"
}
```

Or:

```
{
  myTerm : "KO"
}
```

I would like to use json facets (or any other tool) to get the percent of documents having `myTerm : "OK"`. If i have 100 documents, 40 with `myTerm : "OK"` and 60 with `myTerm : "KO"` i would like to get something like:

```
"facets":{
  "count":100,
  "myTerms":{
    "buckets":[{
        "val":"OK",
        "count":40,
        "percent":40 <------
      }, {
        "val":"KO",
        "count":60
        "percent":60 <------
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This requirement seems trivial to me, but it seems I'm not able to figure out how to get it done.

Comment: Any reason why that calculation has to be performed in Solr? It'd be trivial to fix in your display layer.

Comment: Good question. I'm developing a configurable platform that processes data extracted from solr. My platform allows users to extract values from solr responses using JSonPath expressions, so i need to compute the ratio on solr.